# Android ProgressDailog crashes on dismiss while in a thread

Tags: java, android, handler

Hi I am trying to execute the code below it suppose to open a loading dialog and dismiss it in the `if` statement.

here is the code:

```
loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
         {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {

                final ProgressDialog progress  = ProgressDialog.show(thisActivity, "Please wait", "Loading please wait..", true);
                Thread loginThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void run() 
                    {

                        try
                        {
                            boolean userAllowed = login.loginUser(userEmail.getText().toString(), userPass.getText().toString());
                            if(userAllowed) 
                            {
                                progress.dismiss();
                                startActivity(mainPage);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                progress.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Invalide email and password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) 
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "There is some problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
                });
                loginThread.start();
            }
         });
```

the logCat error output is:

```
05-09 22:37:26.508: E/AndroidRuntime(24820): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1306
05-09 22:37:26.508: E/AndroidRuntime(24820): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
05-09 22:37:26.508: E/AndroidRuntime(24820):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:197)
05-09 22:37:26.508: E/AndroidRuntime(24820):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:111)
05-09 22:37:26.508: E/AndroidRuntime(24820):    at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:324)
05-09 22:37:26.508: E/AndroidRuntime(24820):    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:91)
05-09 22:37:26.508: E/AndroidRuntime(24820):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:238)
05-09 22:37:26.508: E/AndroidRuntime(24820):    at com.shale.activities.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:93)
05-09 22:37:26.508: E/AndroidRuntime(24820):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

My reference was [this](http://androiddesk.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/creating-a-progress-dialog-in-android/) tutorial.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as in Log :

> RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not
>   called Looper.prepare()

means you are trying to update or access UI elements from non ui Thread . so you will need to use [Activity.runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) , [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) or `AsyncTask` for updating or accessing UI from other Thread. do it as:

```
 Your_Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
            //update Ui elements here
        }
     });
```

Comment: @VladIoffe : change your code as http://pastebin.com/QD1cLhGB using runOnUiThread

Answer (score 1):

You can't do anything UI related (including dismissing dialogs) unless you're on the UI thread.  You need to offload that via a runOnUiThread or by passing a message to a handler on the UI thread.  Or better yet-  make that thread an AsyncTask and do it in the onPostExecute()

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the above would be to send a broadcast and have a BroadcastReceiver handle receiving that broadcast and act upon it as you wish.